# Can I put a 4 A power supply on a device that needs 4 mA?

Tags: current

I had a power supply die, and we have universals. But the original power supply did 12 V 400 mA. The universal one we have does 12 V 4.5 A.

I know theory says its fine, it'll only take what it needs. I'm just curious if real world physics behaves the same with the hardware. It is was something like 4 A & 5 A I would be more comfortable, but its 400 mA vs 4.5 A. It's that 10x current that worries me.

Comment: 4.5 A is 1125 times the current, not 10 times. What power supply did you have that's only rated for 4 mA? That figure is probably incorrect if you're talking about an AC to DC converting power supply such as a wall wart.

Comment: Power supply may have requirement for minimal load. Read the spec.

Comment: typo, should have said 400mA

Comment: Thought experiment: what will happen if you plug a 20 W lamp into your domestic supply which is powered by the national grid which can supply gigawatts?

Comment: Simple, non-smart answer.  Yes you can, It's the voltage that has to match.  The load extracts the current it needs, rather like a tap connected to a tank of water.

Comment: The 1mA clock in a car runs fine from the 600A battery.

Comment: Just making sure. I understand theoretically should work fine, but I personally hadnt mismatched current that high of a difference.